# The method withDefaults() is undefined for the type SecurityConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm building a spring application with spring security. I have added basic authentication of a username and password in the code. I want to access APIs via a reactjs web app with this basic authentication. For this, I'm trying to add the cors policy.

In the security configuration of spring security, I'm getting the error:
**The method withDefaults() is undefined for the type SecurityConfiguration**

I have got all the necessary dependencies installed.
What can be the possible solution?

Attaching my code below.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.CorsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .cors(withDefaults())  //getting the error here
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").authenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your code and error message in your question, not as an image. Also, you have not asked a question.

Comment: you don't have any method with name `withDefaults` in your `SecurityConfiguration` class.

Answer (score 54):

Your `SecurityConfiguration`, nor the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` have a method `withDefaults()`. You need to add a static import:

```
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
```

Comment: Any idea why this is not in [the Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors)? I may be missing something.

Comment: @AugustJanse I guess to reduce the number of necessary lines in the examples, they don't show all imports and that they assume people will use a suitable IDE that will suggest the necessary static import.